# Hiding an element when clicking on an embedded video

Tags: jquery, video, hide

So, I had to place a "play" button on top of an embedded video. I thought it would be easy to hide the button when clicking the video using something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $(document).click(function() {     
    $("#play-icon").hide();
});
});
```

Which hides the button if I click anywhere else on the page. Only when I click on the actual video itself it doesn't hide! When I inspect the video, the most obvious class is ".poster" - but that doesn't seem to hide it. I tried using click on "iframe" to hide it but that doesn't do it either! What am I missing? Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: iframes have their own `window` and events in that window do not bubble up to parent page window

Comment: Are you at least able to trigger a video playback (the iFrame) from your own custom button on your page? Anyways all I'm thinking is just put an invisible "hotspot" over the iFrame (using `Z-index` for layering above video). This means a `div` with zero alpha on its `style=` settings. Then clicking on it makes the video play and the `div` can be destroyed or given zero dimensions.